# Bilinear form over C

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, inner-products, linear-transformations, bilinear-form

Let $f:V\times V \rightarrow \Bbb C$ be a bilinear form in a finite inner product space. Will there always be a single linear transformation $T:V\rightarrow V$ for which $f(v,u) = \langle Tv,u\rangle$ for each $v,u\in V$. If not - what's an example of this not happening?

(I can prove this for bilinear forms $f:V\times V \rightarrow \Bbb R$, but can't see if the same applies to $\Bbb C$).

Comment: Where does your proof in the real case fail?

Comment: Possibly related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1572109/biliniear-form-to-inner-product

Comment: The map $\langle Tv, u\rangle$ is not actually bilinear over $\Bbb C$, so this will never work.

Comment: Can you explain? @Omnomnomnom Why is the inner product not bilinear?

Comment: @byteSlayer The inner product is bi-additive, but one of two components does not 'return' scalar product to own form. The complex inner product is (left or right, not both) linear and conjugate symmetric.

Comment: Over $\Bbb C$, the inner product is *sesquilinear*